# What is the standard way to send messages between NgController and NgComponent in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a controller that needs to get some info from a component. Each are getting created by angular through the dom. I understand that components update the models that are given to them which can be provided by the controller. What is the angular way to notify the controller about those changes in the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say that you want a controller to be notified about a change from a component isn't really the correct way to think about what is going on.

In the controller, some type of data model is represented and projected to a view using the current $scope of the controller. When a DOM element (component I'm assuming from your terminology) wants to update the model that the controller is providing, that model is bound via a directive (commonly ng-model) to a component. When that component changes the model, the data is updated automatically because of the directive and the data binding.

Comment: Correct - and the next step is to make the controller aware that the model has been updated. What's the standard way to do that?

Comment: If you mean to trigger some other action based on a scope value changing, then putting a watch on that value will fire a callback with  the new and old values like @marfarma has shown.

Comment: Dart docs for angular $watch: http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.core/Scope.html#$watch

Comment: I ended up fixing this by *not using a component*. I just dropped the component html back into my main html and pulled the component code out into a regular class.

Answer (score 2):

See [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

```
//$scope.$watch(<function/expression>, <handler>);

$scope.$watch('foo', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal, oldVal);
});
```

Also of interest:

```
$scope.$on()
$scope.$emit()
$scope.$broadcase()
$scopt.$watchCollection()
```

Comment: Is this the same for angular in Dart?

Comment: Very similar. It's often not nrcessary to utilize the scope as AngularDart sets changing values using setters of the controller. But the things you listed are available.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I had a problem while attempting to solve this myself where I was using a StreamController to push updates from the component to the controller. At instantiation the stream was subscribed to but at the time of the event (update) the stream had no subscribers, yet none of my code removed the subscription. I figured it was angular magic. Have any insights on that?

Comment: @schellsan can you please create a new question and add some code to demonstrate what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, I'll link it here once I have a moment to do that.