# AngularDart NgComponent is absent until browser resize

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dart, angular-dart

I'm building a project using AngularDart and bootstrap. My project includes an NgComponent that is being rendered in a shadow dom. On load there seems to be a 1 out of 5 chance the component will render visibly on the page. The other 4 out of 5 times it takes a browser resize (to where the responsive bootstrap css snaps back) in order to see the component. Is this just some funky css or what?

Comment: We've seen this bug on early versions of Dartium (pre Dart 1.0), but it is very difficult to reproduce.  What browser are you using?  Could you post a link to your component?

Comment: I'm using Dartium packaged with Dart Editor version 1.0.0_r30798 (STABLE). I've since fixed the problem by *not using a component* (http://stackoverflow.com/q/21415998/223455). I will try to recreate this ASAP.

Comment: What was the conclusion?

Comment: Ultimately I stripped out the NgComponent all together. I decided angular does a lot of magic behind the scenes and that I should probably hold out on complicated angular schemes until my dart skills are a little more mature. You can see the link above for a little more info.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is when an error occurs. When you have set `class="ng-cloak"` Angular hides the content and when the initialization of Angular fails at some point it doesn't come to the point where it unhides the content.   Check the output in DartEditor or Development console.

Comment: I've removed all instances of ng-cloak and both consoles are clear, almost. There are some notes about invalid css that have been there since including bootstrap.

Comment: Invalid CSS property value: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite
Invalid CSS property value: transform 0.3s ease-out
Invalid CSS property declaration at: /
Invalid CSS property value: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite
Invalid CSS property value: transform .3s ease-out
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: Invalid CSS is normally vendor prefixes for other browsers.
This was my only idea.